# ssh multihop with gssapi

Tags: ssh, gssapi

I have set of linux machines configured with GSSAPI SSO. After logging in to first machine (jump host) with password, I can connect by SSH to all other machines with kerberos ticket. Now I'd like to automate connections to other hosts. I've tried with ProxyCommand and netcat but it doesn't work. It there any way to make it working ?

Comment: *doesn't work* is not an diagnose.

Comment: With ProxyCommand I need to put password twice, I suspect that ticket from jump host is not forwarded.

Comment: No, `ProxyCommand` is using your local authentication (by design). If you would have ticket on your local host, it would work for you.

Comment: Is there any other solution which will work ?

Comment: I can think of `ssh jumpbox ssh otherhost`. But it is not elegant nor supported by `ssh_config`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.